# Enter different color text in an html attribute

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am using asp.net and i would like to fill a text attribute of a table cell with different color depending on a parameter. For example:

```
TableCell dataCell= new TableCell();
            foreach (var o in results)
            {
                TimeSpan timeDiff = (DateTime.Now - o.time);
                if (timeDiff.TotalSeconds < 60.0)
                {
                    //Here with green color
                    dataCell.Text += o.name;
                    //I tried dataCell.Text += string.Format("<p //style=\"color":green\" src='{0}'>", o.name); but doesn't work. 
                }
                else
                {
                    //Here with red color
                    dataCell.Text += o.name;
                }                   
            }
            TRow.Cells.Add(dataCell);
```

I want the text in a single line so `<h3>`, `<div>` and `<p>` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`ForeColor` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to set it for the compete cell:

```
if (timeDiff.TotalSeconds < 60.0)
{
    //Here with green color
    dataCell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    dataCell.Text += o.name;
    //I tried dataCell.Text += string.Format("<p //style=\"color":green\" src='{0}'>", o.name); but doesn't work. 
}
else
{
    //Here with red color
    dataCell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.red;
    dataCell.Text += o.name;
}
```

otherwise you could add other controls to the cell, for example `Labels`. But note that you need to re-create every dynamically created control on every postback.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i tried it. The problem is that the text will hold the color of the last value. I want every value independent from the others. How can i use the `Labels` with a single text attribute?

Comment: @George: instead of `dataCell.Text += o.name`(concatenating strings) you could add `Label` controls to the cell. Every label gets it's own `ForeColor` and `Text`.

Comment: you can have text box with border as 0 and set bg color for same, if it will  work

Comment: @George: yes, something like that ;)